# PHP date format, AM and PM reversed

Tags: php, datetime, date-format, unix-timestamp, strtotime

I am echoing out a date with the following code:

```
<?php echo date('h:i A', strtotime($catch[0]['catch_date'])); ?>
```

If I add it at 1:50PM it shows as: 1:50AM when echo'd out instead of showing PM.

I am stumped on this one. Any ideas?

Dates are being entered at the time of addition as:

```
'catch_date' => date('Y-m-d h:i:s')
```

Comment: What is the value of `$catch[0]['catch_date']`?

Comment: It gets entered into the database as:

'catch_date' => date('Y-m-d h:i:s');

Comment: When you do `date("Y-m-d h:i:s")` you lose the real hour. use `H` instead.

Answer (score 1):

You are using the wrong format.

From the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php):-

> h 12-hour format of an hour with leading zeros    01 through 12
>   H 24-hour format of an hour with leading zeros    00 through 23

So you need to change your code to:-

```
'catch_date' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s')
```

Answer (score 1):

You should set the **default time zone** before printing out the date. Example:

```
date_default_timezone_set('Pacific/Auckland');
```

And here is a full list of supported time zones:
https://www.php.net/manual/en/timezones.php